# Django model filter by DateField not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Trying to filter a Django model by DateField. But the filter does not work.

```
Model.objects.filter(delivery_date=date)
```

Where delivery_date is of type DateField and date is of type <class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: Have you tried with `Model.objects.filter(delivery_date__date=date)`

Comment: What do you mean by: "_But the filter does not work_"? Do you get an error? Do you get incorrect / unexpected results? You are not being very clear here...

Comment: No I do not get a error but the models with other delivery dates are displayed

Comment: Then you would need to show us some more code, what you show currently will not reproduce your problem. 1) Show your model (relevant parts of it). 2) Show your view that makes this query. 3) Show the part of the template where you display these results. Please see how to write a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime and special attribut **date** with gte or lte depending on what you are trying to achieve :

```
Model.objects.filter(delivery_date__date__gte=datetime(2021, 06, 27))
```

or with DateField :

```
Model.objects.filter(delivery_date__date=datetime(2021, 06, 27))
```

Comment: can't I do it with datefield?

Comment: when I use __date with a datefield i get a error saying "Unsupported lookup 'date' for DateField or join on the field not permitted."